How to prevent LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid element from rearranging themselves?
I need a LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid with two columns, and the elements in a fixed relative position inside the grid.
For example, if I have 4 elements, all collapsed, they will be like this:
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

When the user clicks the first element, it will expand, but I need to keep the third element below it, like this:
| 1 | 2 |
|   | 4 |
| _ |
| 3 |

What actually happens is that the third element will move to the forth element's position, like so:
| 1 | 2 |
|   | 3 |
| _ | 4 |

Is there a way to prevent this shifting the elements from one column to the other?

That's not how LazyGrids work. You cannot define a specific column for an element since you only provide a single, one-dimensional list of items. How these are distributed among the two-dimensional grid is out of your control. That's actually the point of it: You just dump some items in the grid, and it will automatically figure out a nice arrangement. When an item changes its size the grid will recalculate the arrangement. I don't think that what you want can be done with a grid.

I thought there could be a way to change how the column items are filled. instead of left-right-left-right, do it like left-left-right-right

You might want to take a look at ContextualFlowColumn. Looking at the documentation, and not knowing how you are expanding your 'elements'/views, this seems to match what you might be looking for; lazy loading behavior while being able to expand/collapse items.

Thanks for the suggestion. My grid needs to have different cell heights, so this doesn't work. Sorry for the poor example, I see how it looks like the cells would always have a height of X * ROW_HEIGHT, but it actually can expand to any height.
